# Bitnami Redmine でインストールした MySQL への VBA からの接続方法について教えてください

Tags: mysql, vba, bitnami

BitnamiからRedmineをインストールしました。

RedmineのデータをExcelで使用したいため、VBAを使ってMySQLに接続してデータを取得したいのですが、接続方法がわかりません。

VBAからはMySQL ODBCで接続しようと思っていますが、ODBCのSERVERにはIPアドレスを入れればよいのでしょうか。試しに `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` と入れましたが、エラーとなりました。

なお、RedmineやphpMyAdminにはサーバーのIPアドレスから接続できることは確認しています。

MySQL (Redmine) は Linux 版を使用しており、Google Cloud 上の CentOS にインストールしています。

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

bitnamiからredmineをインストールとのことですが、稼働させているOSと、インストールの形態（ローカルホスト上での直接動作、ローカルホスト上にゲストOSいれての動作←OVAでの提供があるので等）の情報があると切り分けられるかと思います。

ODBCはhttpプロトコルでの接続ではないので、`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`ではありません。
また、ODBC接続にはmysqlのアカウント情報が必要なので、まずはその確認をしましょう。

---

```
cat /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/database.yml
```

このファイルに必要な情報が書いてあるはずです。
参考までに、私の環境では以下の様に記載されていました。これを使ってODBC接続してください。

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: bitnami_redmine
  host: localhost
  username: bitnami
  password: xxxxxxxx(秘密)
  xxxxxx
```

気を付けていただきたいのは、hostです。どうやらこの環境のMysqlserverがlocalhostからの
アクセスしか受け付けていないのか、ファイアウォールで遮断しているのかlocalhost以外では接続できませんでした。なので、別ホストからの接続はこのあと、ちょっとハードルがありそうです。

今回は検証のため、VirtualBoxにbitnami提供のOVAをインポートして確認してみています。
ちなみにゲスト上で以下のコマンドでの接続は問題なく可能でした。

```
> mysql -u bitnami -h localhost -D bitnami_redmine -p
```

bitnamiに統合デスクトップ環境が入れられていないので、詳細なログをつけられなくてごめんなさい。（コマンドのコピペできない。)

Comment: また検証までしていただき、ありがとうございます。別ホストからの接続はハードルありですか・・・。hostですが、自分のPCではなく外部のサーバーにあるので、`http://`を省いたIPアドレス（というのでしょうか）を入れるのかと思っているのですが、間違えていますでしょうか。

Comment: IPアドレスは、xxx。xxx。xxx。xxxのアドレスの認識でOKですが、私の設定と同じ場合、localhost = 通常127.0.0.1のループバックアドレスでの待ち受けになっているので、自ホストからのみ接続可能で、外からの接続はできないのでは？と考えられます。この場合、MySQLの設定を変えるのかfirewalldの設定をかえるのか、どちらかの手当てが必要だと思われます。（多分、前者）